# Update multiple records using subquery oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables Table_A and Table_B
Table_A has columns Id and description
Table_B has columns Id, description and status.
Now I have to update description column in Table_A for records with matching Id and a status value 'U' in Table_B. I used the following query

Update Test_A 
  SET test_a.description = (SELECT test_b.description
                            From Test_B 
                            Where Test_A.id = Test_B.id 
                            And Test_B.Status='U') 
  Where EXISTS (SELECT id
                From Test_B 
                WHERE test_a.id = test_b.id);

But this query not only updates the records with matching ID and status as 'U', but also updates the other rows in Table_A with description as null. I have some sample data prior to update and after update

### Table_A

ID | Description |
1  | A           |
2  | B           |
3  | C           |

### Table_B

ID | Description | Status |
1  | AA          |N       |
3  | CC          |U       |

And after I run the query, I am getting the following results

### Table_A

ID | Description |
1  | AA          |
2  | B           |
3  | (null)      |

Since the flag for ID 3 is not 'U', it is not being selected from Table_B, but is being updated in Table_A. But I was expecting the Table_A record with Id 1 alone to be updated and all other records intact. Can someone please help me to identify where I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add extra condition in your where clause:

```
Update Test_A 
   SET test_a.description 
          = (SELECT test_b.description From Test_B Where Test_A.id = Test_B.id And Test_B.Status='U') 
Where EXISTS (SELECT id From Test_B WHERE test_a.id = test_b.id And Test_B.Status='U');
```

If there are no NULL descriptions in TEST_B you may try this:

```
Update Test_A 
   SET test_a.description 
          = NVL((SELECT test_b.description From Test_B Where Test_A.id = Test_B.id And Test_B.Status='U'), test_a.description);
```

In this case all rows will be updated, but if the correlated subquery returns NULL the old value will remain

Comment: That works. The second query was what I was looking for. Thanks